# xsl:if test = there are NO matching elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

Given XML like this

```
<data>
    <item temp="cool"/>
    <item temp="hot"/>
    <item temp="hot"/>
    <item temp="lukewarm"/>
</data>
```

I can easily test if anything is hot:

```
<xsl:if test="/data/item/@temp = 'hot'">
    Something's hot in here
</xsl:if>
```

But it's a bit convoluted for me to test if nothing is hot:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/data/item/@temp = 'hot'"></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        Nothing's hot in here.
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I have several cases where I just want to append some elements in the not case, so I would like to eliminate extra code.

Is there anyway I can write this into one test statement?

BTW this does not work

```
<xsl:if test="/data/item/@temp != 'hot'">
    Nothing's hot in here
</xsl:if>
```

because it passes as long as one thing is not hot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as the XPath: `not(/data/item[@temp='hot'])`

This translates to `where there does not exist an <item> that has a "temp" attribute with value "hot"`

Comment: `!=` is used to compare values. `not()` is used on sets of nodes.